# physicsBody: Could not create physics body (simulator error)

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, textures

I keep getting this error "physicsBody: Could not create physics body". I've checked what is causing the error and it is this line of code:

```
node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: node.texture!, size: node.texture!.size())
```

However, this error only occurs on the simulator. I don't get this error on my iPhone...

My iPhone is running iOS 13.4.1 and the target build is iOS 13.4.

Is this a glitch?

Cheers!

Comment: Looks like a bug https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123940

Comment: Yeah you're right. Annoying. Thanks though!